# Why won't my pc run Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: 14.10

I am new to this so I'm  sorry if this question has been asked before. I have just installed Ubuntu desktop on my old XP machine but it's running very very slow the processor is maxed out. according to the system requirements it should be fine. My PC is running on an AMD sampron 3100+ processor running at 1800MHZ with 1gig of DDR RAM can anyone help

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't be installing 14.10. It's no longer supported. Either use 14.04 or 15.10.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely with your graphics card, ubuntu is quite heavy on that front, your best bet would probably be to install xubuntu or lubuntu, alternatively you could buy a new video card if you really wanted to run unity

Answer (score 0):

I second regarding the graphic card as possible source for the heavy load & slowness of your system. But as you already have a working base install i would recommend to just install another desktop environment (versus installing from another ubuntu flavor install medium).

So instead of **Unity** (which is ubuntus default) give **XFCE** (just one example of the possible alternatives) a try.

You could achieve that by running:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop
```

Then logout and while logging in choose xfce instead of unity.

Please report back if that helps regarding the slow system performance